# Yesod Persistent - Using two names for a column

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod

Suppose I have a column `foo` and I want to use it in Haskell as `boo`, how could I do something similar to this:

```
MyEntity
  boo 'foo' Text
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#change-tablecollection-id-field-name-andor-type-persistent--21:

```
MyEntity
    boo Text sql=foo
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any issue using this approach? I have to use a database which wasn't defined very well, but changing the column names now is unmanageable.

Comment: @FtheBuilder I doubt there are downsides, it sounds like a rather simple operation. If you do find an issue, the persistent project does look quite actively developed so it's quite likely it'll get fixed.